# NuGet package files missing

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget, mvvm-light

I am making a program in C# WPF with the mvvm-light NuGet package. It worked well for some time but now I get errors on `InitializeComponent()` of my MainwWindow. When I try to debug, I get deeper and deeper in the program until it says:

> "ViewModelBase.cs not found"

ViewModelBase.cs is a file in the NugetPackage of the mvvm-ligth library.

Does anyone know how this is possible/solved?

Comment: I removed a tag from your question's title. Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) why.

Comment: Is ViewModelBase.cs referenced by your project?

Comment: check the csproj for it.

Comment: You installed MvvmLight with Nuget, but you don't have the sources like ViewModelBase.cs. So you get an error when you want to step into those files: they are not downloaded with the Nuget package.

Comment: but how can i properly debug in that case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you correctly added package: Right click on solution -> Restore nuGet packages.

If you are not sure: Right click on solution -> Manage nuGet packages for solution -> Select MvvmLight package and check that package has been installed for the project which is throwing that error (checkbox for that project should be ticked).

Comment: Everything is added correctly, when i am writing code is autocompletes the classes of the nuget.

Comment: When you say that you go deeper and deeper into the program, what does that mean? Which line of code throws that error? When InitializeComponent() throws an exception, that usually means that something is wrong with xaml... Can you be a little more specific about your problem?

Comment: it was something in the viewmodel that gave a notImplementedException and that gave error in xaml. thanks